# How to output tromino puzzle in this special way?

Tags: c, output

I am solving a tromino puzzle problem on a online judge system, and it requires all L-piece should be should be represented by a single lowercase letter (a-z), with none of the surrounding letters same as itself. Two different L-pieces can be represented by the same letter, as long as they are not adjacent.And i don't know how to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int a[1000][1000];
int num = 1;
void tromino(int x, int y, int size, int bx, int by)
{
    int tx, ty, i;
    tx = x + size/2;
    ty = y + size/2;
    int bx4[4] = {tx, tx-1, tx-1, tx};
    int by4[4] = {ty-1, ty-1, ty, ty};
    if (bx >= tx&&by < ty)
        bx4[0] = bx, by4[0] = by;
    else if (bx < tx&&by < ty)
        bx4[1] = bx, by4[1] = by;
    else if (bx < tx&&by >= ty) 
        bx4[2] = bx, by4[2] = by;
    else
        bx4[3] = bx, by4[3] = by;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (bx4[i] == bx&&by4[i] == by) continue;
        a[by4[i]][bx4[i]] = num;
    }
    num++;
    if (size > 2)
    {
        tromino(tx, y, size/2, bx4[0], by4[0]);
        tromino(x, y, size/2, bx4[1], by4[1]);
        tromino(x, ty, size/2, bx4[2], by4[2]);
        tromino(tx, ty, size/2, bx4[3], by4[3]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size, n, bx, by, i, j;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &by, &bx);
    size = pow(2, n);
    by--, bx--;
    a[by][bx] = 0;
    tromino(0, 0, size, bx, by);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i == by&&j == bx)
                printf("* ");
            else 
                printf("%c ", 97 + a[i][j]%26);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The first input is the size of the board (2^n * 2^n)
The second the third is the the row and the column in which the ``hole'' is located.

```
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i == by&&j == bx)
                printf("* ");
            else 
                printf("%c ", 97 + a[i][j]%26);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The character which represent 'L-piece' will be adjacent in some case.

Comment: The idea of online challenges is to challenge your skill, not make you to relay this challenge on the SO community.

Comment: Please try to avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you with the integer value `97` mean the [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character `'a'` then *say* so by using the character `'a'` instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Im sorry ,i had thought about this for a month, but i still dont know how to do , so i want ask someone

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, ok, i will change this habbit

Comment: as part of the text of your question, please post a link to the problem your trying to solve